# Back button reload cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am making an application in cordova apache and the problem I find is that I make some modifications with JQuery on the main page, and there is a link to an internal page.

The problem is that if I go back to the previous page, that page reloads and the previous modifications are not kept.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Which JS framework are you using?

Comment: Please provide js code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution so far that I have found is as under

- Consider that you have a page A and you are going to page B after you click a link on page A
- To that link, you create an anchor point (dynamic value) and write an onload condition event to check if the anchor point exists, if yes, then window.scroll to that anchor point, if No then do nothing.
- on the link on page A pass a value that is same as the dynamic value of the anchor point and save that value on page B using localstorage.setItem ...so that when you perform a back event from page B, Page A checks for any localstorage and if it exists, it scrolls the page to that anchor point

in case of data, you can still use the localStorage method or sqllite